# Automate Nodejs script to take input file after some interval from a folder?

Tags: php, node.js

I have a Nodejs script which is currently taking image file and sent it to server via API,

Now I am wondering if there is any method through which **Nodejs scripts runs every small interval and check if new file is present and if present sent it over to server VIA API.**

Is there any method in Nodejs or in PHP too ?

Example:

I have API - https://localhost:4200/images

Above API takes an image input and sent it to server, currently I am sending images by manually selecting now I need to automate this.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to the question at hand. You're specifically asking about nodejs, so I removed the PHP tag.

Comment: I have added PHP because I am seeking solution in PHP or nodejs

Comment: Almost all question that contains multiple language "choices" are being closed for being unfocused. We're here to answer _specific_ issues you might run into with your implementation, not to recommend languages or high level solutions. Always make sure you've done the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking as well.

Comment: If you're on linux, you can also read up on [crontab](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) where you can schedule commands to be run at certain intervals (like executing some code you've written in what ever language).